# Podio - How can we re-schedule other future tasks?

Tags: pm-software, tools

Does anyone know whether it is possible to re-schedule several tasks at once with [Podio](https://podio.com/)?

Let's say I have one task that needs to pass to another day. I wish that all others future tasks also adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mem, welcome to PMSE! Our site is more for questions about the field of project management. For help with Podio, check out their [support site](https://help.podio.com/home) where you're more likely to find an answer from an authority on the software. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

After contacting Podio Support, at this date, it's not possible to do such things.